# Extract hand from kinect dataset using image processing

Tags: image-processing, kinect, kinect-sdk

I downloaded the kinect sensor datasets (depth(textfile) and image)because kinect is expensive.I don't know how to proceed with the dataset?I have to extract the hand from the image.i can't use kinectSDK because it works only if kinect sensor is connected.So i decided to extract hand from the image using image processing.Can anyone please suggest any algorithm for that? or can I extract hand by means of other methods?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which images do you mean? Yes you can track hands by other methods. But without images we cannot decide which methods are good.

Comment: @Trilarion-I downloaded  the datsets (image and depth) from  this website :http: // eeeweba.ntu.edu.sg / computervision / people / home / renzhou / HandGesture.htm

Answer (score 0):

color image and depth information can be used for hand detection,

i think you can use nearest skin region to camera as the hand, because in the dataset hand placed front of body.

Comment: I didnt use sensor .I just use datasets from the sensor and I am going to detect the hand and extract it from full image .so how can i find nearest skin region to camera?

Comment: 1- extract skin pixels from image by GMM or NN or other methods; 2- remove the individual skin pixel; 3- use size filter for remove the small skin regions (by predefined threshold); 4- find distance of skin regions from kinect by depth info

Comment: Can u suggest any method for processing depth info(.txt file)?so that i can easily extract the hand part.